# Angular property decorator adding to component's lifecycle hooks?

Tags: angular

The following code allows me to add a `@Test()` to my component, however I need to add a command to the ngOnInit hook and it currently replaces the hook within the component.

```
function Test(value:any) {

  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string | symbol) {

    target.ngOnInit = () => {
      console.log("This replaces the component's hook")
    }

  }
}
```

How do I just add to it?

Answer (score 2):

Decorators are actually just functions, A method decorator will be called with the value of the method it’s decorating, and a class decorator will be called with the class to be decorated.

Below decorator is just going to simply log the class to the console:

```
function Console(target) {
  console.log('Our decorated class', target);
}
```

The target will in fact be the class that we decorate, which means we can now decorate any class with our decorator and see it outputted in the console:

```
@Console
class ExampleClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Yo!');
  }
}
```

Taken this from [link to detail decorator](https://toddmotto.com/angular-decorators). And there are tons of example available in google.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, definitely did. Is there a way to add to the component's lifecycle hooks?

Comment: I did not explored much on that. you can follow on that document. also there are many libraries available in git they created these decorations. but you ned to search more to get into there